# Generate AR Pattern files

Tags: design-patterns, augmented-reality

How can I generate pattern files please?
Is it possible to do this in Photoshop?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the images that are tracked by the AR software?

Typically these are simply bitmaps, so Photoshop will work.

Which SDK are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. I am playing around with the FLARManager and FLARToolkit, which ar ports from Java to Flash. FLARToolKit requires 16 bit bitmaps with border around them.

Comment: You can add the border through an image authoring/editing program like Photoshop and output the composite image as a bitmap. Just be sure to use the correct specification for the border (e.g. width and offset ). If you need to add borders programmatically, Photoshop supports a scripting interface to automate these sorts of tasks. Otherwise you could probably use a tool like Processing, which is closer to a programming environment - http://processing.org/